# Getting null value from Web api

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to store a List of strings that are members of a conversation.

```
[DataContract]
public class Conversation
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ConversationName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Administrator { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Members { get; set; }

    public Conversation(string key, string name, string admin, List<string> members)
    {
        Key = key;
        ConversationName = name;
        Administrator = admin;
        Members = members;
    }

    public Conversation()
    {

    }
}
```

I am using Postman to make a Post request to the URI which seems to work fine, returning 201 Created and giving a json object containing the correct info.
This is the json I am posting:

```
{
    "Key": "123",
    "ConversationName": "Test",
    "Administrator": "Ken",
   "Members": ["y@12.com", "f@78.com"]
}
```

However, when I try to get the conversation in a GET method this is the result:

```
{
  "Key": "123",
  "ConversationName": "Test",
  "Administrator": "Ken",
  "Members": null
}
```

These are my functions in my controller:

Post:

```
[HttpPost]
    //[ResponseType(typeof(Conversation))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostConversation(Conversation convo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Conversations.Add(convo);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { name = convo.Key }, convo);
    }
```

GET:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Conversation> GetConversations()
{
    return db.Conversations;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you sotre Members list into your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **post** basically returns the entity as you offer it, which is *with* `Members`, apparently.

The **get** loads a `Conversation` from the database. It can't have any `Members` at that moment, because `Members` is a `List<string>`, which can't possibly be mapped to a database column.

You probably expect the **post** to store the `Members` into the database. This doesn't happen, because you should use `Member` *entities* in stead of strings. `Member` can be a simple class having an `Id` and a `string` property.

Comment: So could if I changed `List<String>` to `List<User>` would this work as it is still a collection?

Comment: I don't know how you define "work", but it `User` entities can be stored in the database as a regular 1-n relationship. Turning them into a list of strings requires some processing after getting the entities from the database.

Comment: I have done this and it is inserting a new User into the table which is resulting in an error `"ExceptionMessage": "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'.` The User I wish to insert however has already been created and should be entered into a Conversation table but not created as a new User. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: We're stepping outside the scope of this question. Please ask a new question showing your new code. It's hard to answer this from one single comment. I think I answered your primary problem. I don't mind looking into subsequent problems, but a new question is a better way to do that.

Comment: I agree thank you for your help I will ask a new question now!